# Git | Игнорируемые коммиты

Tags: git, github

В ходе отправки коммитов на ветку dev а после их слияния с веткой master через интерфейс гитхаба, у меня в истории коммитов появляются коммиты со слияниями, merge pull request и тп.
Если я сделаю форк этого репозитория и захочу подправить историю коммитов(я там как-то 2 одинаковых коммита, и пару пустых) Через git rebase -i То у меня там не будет коммитов со слияниями, там будут только комиты которые были отправленны через гит. И если я вот так захочу что-то там подправить а потом сделать git push --force то у меня в истории коммитов на гитхаб уже не будет коммитов со слияниями вообще, хотя если я напишу git log то там все эти коммиты будут. Как подправить историю коммитов и сохранить эти игнорируемые коммиты?

Спасибо.

Comment: `git rebase -i --rebase-merges` вроде.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat ничего не изменилось

Comment: В смысле не изменилось? Покажите, какой список коммитов вам открывает гит в редакторе в ответ на это.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Виноват, всё работает, трабл случился. Спасибо. А не подскажите как сделать git push с этими коммитами?

Comment: `git push --force`?